# What is the best way to automate deployments windows service and desktop apps

Tags: .net, powershell, deployment, windows-services, automated-deploy

At the moment we are using teamcity for continuous builds.

We need deploying windows services as well as desktop apps into citrix environment.

Thing specific to our setup is many production environments with different versions and configurations running and being deployed in different life cycles.

I remember seeing NANT compared to now superior software which I can not find anymore. I also remember using teamcity to do a release based on tag numbers.

Where can I find some best practices for this kind of deployment?

Comment: found it just now - I was after continuous deployment with psake
http://ryanmichaelwilliams.com/articles/2013/03/17/continuous-deployment-with-psake
will probably end up deleting this question

Comment: why delete it?  Post your findings as an answer to your own question, it is perfectly valid